# It is possible to pre buffer a HTML5 Video using another video element?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, buffer, fragment

I need to pre buffer a video fragment using HTML5 video element. The idea is to play the main video on the first player, and to start to buffer another fragment from the video (same file) on another video element.

Is that possible? Can the first video element access the buffer from the second one?

I've run some tests on Chrome, and it seems that they are different objects, and doesn't do a reference to the same video file buffer.

Comment: i tried everything i couldn't